# Remove a cookie from NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlrequest

I need to expire a specific cookie when making a NSURLRequest, but don't see any way to expire a specific cookie.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are returned as part of a HTTP response (using the `Set-Cookie:` header, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)) and they are maintained by your browser (not the server). It is therefore up to whatever is handling the HTTP responses (in this case, your Objective-C code) to store cookies and pass them to the server with each request.

Therefore it doesn't make sense for you to try to expire cookies in an NSURLRequest because the server you are making a request to doesn't even know about the cookies unless you send them along in the `Cookie:` header of the request.

If you are using `NSURLRequest`, you are going to have to parse cookies from `Set-Cookie:` headers in the response, store them, and then send them along with subsequent requests. Then you can simply choose not to send along a cookie if you want it expired.